# Amazon S3 on wamp localhost SSL error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, amazon-s3

I'm trying to test in PHP Amazon S3 on my localhost but keep getting the same error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'cURL_Exception' with message 'cURL
>   resource: Resource id #69; cURL error: SSL certificate problem, verify
>   that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (cURL
>   error code 60). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
>   for an explanation of error codes.' in
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\application\libraries\awsphp\lib\requestcore\requestcore.class.php:829
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\application\libraries\awsphp\sdk.class.php(1034):
>   RequestCore->send_request() #1
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\application\libraries\awsphp\services\sqs.class.php(250):
>   CFRuntime->authenticate('ListQueues', Array) #2
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\application\libraries\awsphp\services\sqs.class.php(582):
>   AmazonSQS->authenticate('ListQueues', Array) #3
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\application\controllers\uploads.php(33):
>   AmazonSQS->list_queues() #4 [internal function]: Uploads->aw3() #5
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\application\libraries\awsphp\lib\requestcore\requestcore.class.php
>   on line 829

Test code:

```
$sqs = new AmazonSQS();
$response = $sqs->list_queues();
var_dump($response->isOK());
```

I properly installed the AWS SDK to php files and enabled CURL and SSL on me local server. What can I do to make this work? I can't find any help online. I'm using wamp.

Comment: i have a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253812/aws-s3-batch-upload-from-localhost-php-error but the fix below did not work

Answer (score 55, accepted):

1. Get [this file](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and save it to your hard drive. Call it `cacert.pem`.
2. Configure [`curl.cainfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php#ini.curl.cainfo) in php.ini with the full path to the file downloaded in step 1.
3. Restart Apache.

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to find out *why* this fixes it, all the information you need can be found in the links above.

Comment: Cheers for that! To my understanding I need a valid SSL certificate to connect to the right server. I added `curl.cainfo = "C:/cacert.pem"` at the bottom of my php.ini file and the errors are gone. It also works adding `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` and `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` but it's not secure

Comment: wow finally found a proper solution after hundreds of useless 'solutions' like `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! For me, I was having trouble on WAMP using the AWS SDK (SQS).  After reading this post, I copied the cacert.pem file that was included in the AWS SDK (here https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/tree/master/lib/requestcore) to C:\code\cacert.pem, and then I added this to the bottom of my php.ini: `curl.cainfo = C:\code\cacert.pem`

Comment: I would have loved to give more ups , i have been wasting so much time to solve this ! Thanks

Comment: For me configuring curl.cainfo didn't work but instead the same steps except that the full path should be set to openssl.cafile in the php.ini

Comment: I can confirm this to be a solution for localhost (XAMPP)

Comment: And Devember 2019!

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you running on Windows?
2. Did you take the time to run the SDK Compatibility Test that comes bundled with the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=215107) you can't work with Amazon AWS on localhost..

Comment: without internet connection. But you do can work with AWS on localhost if you have internet connection.

Comment: I am on Xampp Windows. Accepted answer did the job