# AWS S3 batch upload from localhost php error

Tags: php, amazon-s3, curl-multi

I am trying to **batch/bulk** upload from localhost (xampp) to my `S3` bucket.
It seems to work for about 6 items then i get an error message:
The cURL error says `Failed sending network data.` from http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'cURL_Multi_Exception' with message 'cURL resource: Resource id #34; cURL error: SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 0 (cURL error code 55). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\path\to\my\files\sdk-1.5.14\lib\requestcore\requestcore.class.php on line 902
```

and

```
cURL_Multi_Exception: cURL resource: Resource id #34; cURL error: SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 0 (cURL error code 55). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes. in D:\xampp\htdocs\path\to\my\files\sdk-1.5.14\lib\requestcore\requestcore.class.php on line 902
```

heres my php. It gets a list of images from a directory and from that loop I wish to batch upload those items to `S3`.

```
require_once('sdk-1.5.14/sdk.class.php');
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
//$s3->disable_ssl_verification(); //this didnt fix it

$folder = "./../"; 
$handle = opendir($folder); 

# Making an array of files in a directory to upload to S3
while ($file = readdir($handle)) 
{ 
        $files[] = $file; 
} 
closedir($handle);

foreach ($files as $file) { 
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
        if(isset($path_parts['extension']) && $path_parts['extension'] != '') {

                // local path
                $fileTempName = "D:/xampp/htdocs/path/to/my/files/";

                //batch
                $response = $s3->batch()->create_object('bucketname', "tempdirectory/" . $file, array(
                        'fileUpload' => fopen($fileTempName . $file, 'r'),
                        'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
                ));

        }

}
$s3->batch()->send();
```

**update:**
after making changes to `congig.inc.php` i am now getting error messages:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'cURL_Multi_Exception' with message 'cURL resource: Resource id #149; cURL error: Failed connect to mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443; No error (cURL error code 7). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\sdk-1.5.14\lib\requestcore\requestcore.class.php on line 902`


`cURL_Multi_Exception: cURL resource: Resource id #149; cURL error: Failed connect to prayerbucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443; No error (cURL error code 7). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes. in D:\xampp\htdocs\sdk-1.5.14\lib\requestcore\requestcore.class.php on line 902`

Comment: as far as i know, you can't test amazon aw3 from localhost. I had to upload my files to my host and try live.

Comment: @CyberJunkie i see, have you heard of any workarounds?

Comment: this is all I know about it https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=215107

Comment: I get this errors too, i try to set up limit batch queue = 2

Comment: @Sergey ok,  where do i set this?

Comment: I have created this way: $batch = new CFBatchRequest(2); $s3->batch($batch); But need call $s3->batch()->send() many time;  And batch send is not good :(

Comment: And now sdk is 1.5.15 (Panther)

Comment: @Sergey i dont get the error but it does not upoad to s3 `$response1 = $s3->batch($batch)->create_object('mybucket', "path/to/my/" . $file, array(
       'fileUpload' => fopen($fileuserName1 . $file, 'r'),
       'contentType' => 'image/' . $extension,
       'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
     ));`

Comment: @Sergey it worked, the fix was in the placement of `$s3->batch()->send();` need to place it in the loop of `$s3->batch($batch)->create_object()`. please rephrase this and i will accept as answer

Comment: Sorry, if you set batch to loop, you do not need batch :) just send it normal. Or you mean next loop for work only batch?

Comment: @tq, I explain batch work with AmazonSDK. Multi curl is depends from your speed outgoing connections. If you have less than 1Mb and you send not big file - 2 instance is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set limit for batch:

```
$batch = new CFBatchRequest(2); // only two instance at once

foreach ($files as $file) { 
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
        if(isset($path_parts['extension']) && $path_parts['extension'] != '') {

                // local path
                $fileTempName = "D:/xampp/htdocs/path/to/my/files/";

                // if batch, it have to return curl's resource
                $curl_handler = $s3->batch($batch)->create_object('bucketname', "tempdirectory/" . $file, array(
                        'fileUpload' => fopen($fileTempName . $file, 'r'),
                        'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
                ));

        }

}
// batch object send queue
$batch->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 'certificate_authority' to true in the config.inc.php.