# CodeIgniter-cURL on self assign certificate

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, curl, https

Im using codeigniter-curl extension (https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl) to call API that return Json format data.

a simple code it will return the result etc

```
$this->curl->simple_get(http://example.com/Json/GetHotDealRedemptionProduct?APIid=888ef4d078ca&Language=en&hash=3709aa6e0efe3c95e955a1981118027a2fde0eddc216b4049e6559af55f50458);
```

everything seem ok until the URL changed to HTTPS.

In order to call SSL url (self signed certificate), i added these few line above my $this->curl->simple_get.... code.

```
$this->curl->create($this->url);
$this->curl->ssl(true, 2, 'assets/AIMS-BSN-WEB01.crt');
```

the cacert.pem i saved from the firefox certificate viewer and place it in my web directory. reference: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

and i get this error.

```
error code: 60
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

i've searched the answer for a day long,

1. changed the php.ini setting [Amazon S3 on wamp localhost SSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910697/amazon-s3-on-wamp-localhost-ssl-error)
2. put false for CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER. it return `SSL: certificate subject name 'AIMS-BSN-WEB01' does not match target host name 'api.example.com'`

all these are not working.

Comment: Try to specify full path to 'assets/cacert.pem'

Comment: yes. in the $this->curl->ssl function it will turn it into realpath
"C:/wamp/www/assets/cacert.pem"

Comment: sorry because is self signed certification the name should be AIMS-BSN-WEB01.crt instead of cacert.pem

Answer (score 1):

ok. i manage to solved it by skipping to verify the peer or host of the certification - [PHP CURL CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135834/php-curl-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-ignored)

and instead of putting FALSE in CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER i use 0.

```
$this->option(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$this->option(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

now it works.

Comment: Horrible choice... You just defeated the point of SSL/TLS. You might as well use ***`aNULL`*** and ***`eNULL`***; or just use plain text.

Comment: @jww. Why don't you give a solution rather than just downvote him? I'm here looking for a solution to get verify_peer to work the way it should and can't find a working answer.

Comment: @AuntJamaima - Downvoting a bad answer and providing a good answer are orthogonal. It seems to me the system [mostly] worked as intended. You avoided a bad answer. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html).

Comment: @AuntJamaima - Also see [CURL SSL with self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27611193/608639) and [Curl error 60, SSL certificate prðblem: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23585500/608639)